# Apply multiple times a Product Partner Fixed Price Promotion

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, promotions

In SAP Commerce v1811 I configured a product partner fixed price promotion such us
"Buy 2 of Product A and get product B at USD 100"
In order to do this I used the **Product perfect partner fixed price** and configured

```
Conditions
CONTAINER_X: Qualifying Products -> A qty >= 1
CONTAINER_Y: Qualifying Products -> B qty >= 1

Actions
target price -> USD 100
qualifying container -> CONTAINER_X->2
target container -> CONTAINER_Y->1
```

I also set the execution max times at 3 but when the promotion it's applied the first time it works perfectly (when I add 2A and 1B) but the second time it's not apllied (when I add 4A and 2B) is not applied.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had to upgrade my version to 1811.6 and it was fixed